# android how to call new activities in toggle button?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-togglebutton

How do I start a new activity when a `ToggleButton` is pressed? Here is what I have so far:

```
public static boolean status = false;

final ToggleButton yes_no = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.yes_no);
yes_no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (status == true) {
                if ((yes_no.isPressed())) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,UserFeedback.class));
                } else if (status) {
                    if (yes_no.isPressed()) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,QuestionScreen.class));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please consider writing some proper text and format your code properly. This makes it easier to understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below:

```
    if (status == true) {
        if ((yes_no.isChecked())) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,UserFeedback.class));

        } else if (status) {
            if (yes_no.isChecked()) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,QuestionScreen.class));

            }
        }
    }
```

Also note that you both 'if cases' are same. Change either one and it will work.